# Преобразование линейных точек звуковой волны в логарифмические

Tags: c++

У меня есть линейный график звуковой волны :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужно получить график звуковой волны в логарифмической форме, а именно :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для этого для каждого образца мне нужно применить формулу для преобразования значения из линейного в логарифмическое.

Я думаю, мне нужно использовать формулу из [этого](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B5%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BB) материала.

Но когда я получаю определенный коэффициент, я не знаю, что с ним делать дальше.

Я хочу отметить, что максимальное значение выборки составляет 32512, а минимальное - 1.

---

Пример преобразования линейного значения выборки в логарифмическое :

```
const double linearSample = 27000;
const double logSample = 20.0 * log10(27000);

// Res: 88.6272753
```

**В моей задаче главным приоритетом является увеличение очень малых значений сэмплов, чтобы выделить их для отображения звука (как показано на 2-м изображении)!**

---

**Upd**

Согласно одной из рекомендаций `MBo`, я применил следующию логику:

```
for (int i = 0; i < samples.size(); ++i) {
    const int16_t curSample = samples[i];
    if (curSample != 0) {
        samples[i] = curSample > 0 ? static_cast<int16_t>(720 * log10(curSample)) : static_cast<int16_t>(-720 * log10(-curSample));
    }
}
```

Вот что получилось при **линейном отображение**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и **логарифмическом отображение**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я попытался отбросить слишком маленькие значения, и вот что произошло:

```
for (int i = 0; i < samples.size(); ++i) {
    const int16_t curSample = samples[i];
    if (curSample != 0) {
        samples[i] = curSample > 50 ? static_cast<int16_t>(720 * log10(curSample)) : ((curSample < -50) ? static_cast<int16_t>(-720 * log10(-curSample)) : curSample);
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не понял, в чем вопрос? *"когда я получаю определенный коэффициент, я не знаю, что с ним делать"* Рисовать график из них?

Comment: Мне нужно сохранить масштаб графика. А именно, при входящем значении 32000 исходящая выборка не должна изменяться, но выборка со значением 400 должна увеличиться в несколько раз, чтобы иметь возможность отобразить ее на графике.

Comment: Не на 360, а в 360 раз. А что, результат на рисунке неправильный?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Прологарифмировав набор значений, вы получаете новый набор значений. Теперь для рисования графика нужна нормировка на минимум и максимум этого нового набора - только и всего.

Если пределы графика фиксированы - просто используйте новые пределы. Например, если для графика амплитуд использовалась шкала, в которой значения -32768...32767 соответствовали координатам по вертикали y_min.. y_max, то теперь эти же y_min.. y_max соответствуют значениям в децибелах -90 дБ..90 дБ (значения по вашей формуле)

```
if (value == 0)
     выводить 0
else if (value > 0)
     выводить 720*log10(value))
else
     выводить -720*log10(-value))
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но, к сожалению, у меня нет возможности иметь другие ограничения. Хочу сказать, что как при входе, у меня есть максимальное значение - `32512`, так и при выходе оно будет таким же. Но вот незначительные значения, такие как `500`, `700`, `1000` и так далее, должны увеличиться благодаря умножению самого себя на определенный коэффициент (по крайней мере, я себе это так представляю). Каким должен быть этот коэффициент я не знаю :)

Comment: если есть возможность пробежаться вначале по всему набору, то можно найти максимальное и минимальное значение и по модулю (abs) выбрать большее.  Теперь можно использовать его как коэффициент - текущее значение сигнала делите на это полученное  и умножаете на обратный логарифм высоты в пикселях в графике и потом берете логарифм

Comment: Как вы раньше график-то строили?

Comment: Умножайте логарифмированные значения на коэффициент 360

Comment: Главное логарифм нуля обойти аккуратно

Comment: @KoVadim Если данные былb бы вещественные, то там ещё проблема значений, меньших единицы бы возникла

Comment: @MBo при умножение логарифмированных значений на коэффициент `720`, получаются слишком большие значения дня слишком малых. Я добавил пример визуализации с вашей рекомендацией. Можете перечитать вопрос.

Comment: Принцип простой - `360 * 20 * log10(32512) ~= 32512`. Да, маленькие значения вырастут относительно больших - в этом и смысл логарифмической шкалы, зато теперь будет видно и значения выше 10000, и выше 1000, и выше 100 (они будут в середине шкалы) и выше 10, и от 1 до 10 - они будут в нижней пятой части графика. У вас значений в последних диапазонах просто мало. Средний рисунок выглядит так, как нужно.

Comment: @MBo Я попытался отбросить слишком маленькие значения, и результат более чем хорош!